# PHP MySQL Secure Connection - Same Server

Tags: php, mysql

I have some `php` scripts that use `mysqli()` to connect to `MySQL` which is located on the same server. I currently have the connection stored outside of my sites `root` and I am using `include()` to make the connection.

For **remote** `MySQL` servers it is recommended to use an `ssh` connection. For my environment, should I take any other measures to secure my connection?

Also is it more of a concern that `mysql` is on the **same** server?

Lastly I am guessing I would want to prevent any errors resulting from the connection being displayed as they would give connection information.

**EDIT**

Im also curious as to if/when I would want to `close()` these connections. I am guessing I would want to close them but only after I am done accessing the database on a particular page.

**EDIT 2**

Still looking for the above information as of 12.11.2019

Comment: Most of the time remote connections are not allowed or at least VERY highly discouraged. Using `ssh` would be considered a minimum requirement if you do need to allow remote connections. You don't need to explicitly close connections. That is done when the PHP script is finished. Use `try/catch` for the connection to make sure no connection information gets "leaked". Also set your logging to always go to the PHP error log instead of having it displayed.